# How to use Windows Small Business Server 2008 to print from a web application?

Tags: php, windows, web-applications, printing, windows-sbs

I'm developing a web application in PHP and we need to print some files/labels from this web application. The web application is hosted on a 3rd party hosting provider. The thermal printers are available in the network which can be accessed via Windows SBS 2008. So both the web application and the SBS server are in 2 different nework.

The windows SBS 2008 can be accessed through a public domain/IP. IIS is currently running on the same server.

Is there any way to print the files from Internet by sending a command to the SBS server, something like API request with authentication via Curl or Soap etc?

Please note: I have limited access to the system, so installing any software on SBS server is not practical.